# sitemap.xml - нужно ли оставлять параметры страниц

Tags: индексация, sitemap

Некоторые генераторы sitemap.xml создают sitemap с учетом GET-параметров.
Поэтому вопрос такой: стоит ли оставлять GET параметры или все-же лучше вырезать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если от GET параметров не зависит адрес конкретной страницы, например example.com/page?pagename=about_us то, в sitemap.xml можно обойтись без них.

Вот, как пример sitemap.xml от MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/sitemaps/en-US/sitemap.xml

```
...
<url>
  <loc>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Animated_PNG_graphics</loc>  
   <lastmod>2014-03-25</lastmod>
</url>
...
```